# Getting an error while trying to run exe from powershell with different credentials

Tags: windows, powershell

Im trying to do something very very simple,
i want to call an exe from powershell using different credentials.
for my test i run this command while powershell session is the root of the exe file:

```
Start-Process ".\blabla.exe" -Credential $(Get-Credential)
```

i then enter the credentials i want (checked 10 times) and still get the following error:
[image]

The Credetials are good, any idea why do i get this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Start-process raises an error when providing Credentials - possible bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7319658/start-process-raises-an-error-when-providing-credentials-possible-bug)

Comment: Is your machine domain joined or part of a work group? Are your credentials local or from a domain?

Comment: Also, which PS version (`$PSVersionTable`)?

Comment: Domain user, PsVER: 5.1, i tried from ISE, Tried from pwoershell command line, and from ISE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it appears powershell cant have user name as "blabla@blabla.bla" the username must be as "domain.something\username"